# parent Div resizes causing controls position in child div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I have got ParentDiv(content) inside i have got the 4 child Divs , i am putting validation summary on top but this not in  div(because its need to re-sized dynamically)  before showing the validation summary its working fine, all Div's are aligning properly its fine.

when I am trying to show the validation summary on top,the parent div goes down ... and all child divs are shrinking and position of  controls  are in child div changed..

I have placed controls are in child divs in individual divs (i.e) one label for one div and one textbox for one div like this...

is there any way to reduce the position change in child divs and i have tried putting min width and minimum height and height and width in percentages(%) and changed the overflow properties to auto and hidden of child div's but all of those didn't worked for me.

I am stucking in this problem since from two days, is there any way to do with css styles  or with jquery..

would any one pls help on this .....

i am using Visual studio (2012) version

this is style for main content page Div

```
#cotent {
   position: relative;
   /*min-height: 440px;*/
   /*height: auto;*/
   /*width: auto;*/
   /*height: auto !important;*/ 
   height: 737px;
   /*height: 100%;*/

   width: 1313px;
   min-height: 840px;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

and this is for one of the child div

```
#leftSideDiv {
   position: relative;  
   top: -20px;
   /*height: 70%;
   width: 70%;*/
   /*display: block;*/
   /*min-height: 95%;
   min-width: 100%;*/
   /*height: 90%;
   width: 95%;*/
   height: 361px;
   width: 529px;
   /*height: auto;
   width: auto;
   left: 19px;
   /*overflow: auto;
   resize: both;*/
   /*margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;*/
   display: inline-block;
}
```

would you pls let me know if u need any more code

and this is the code for child div(leftsideDiv)

```
 <div id="leftSideDiv">
        <asp:Label ID="Label15" Font-Size="Large" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Direct Shipment:"></asp:Label>
        <div id="lblbilltypeDiv">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkBilltyDir" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ChkBilltyDir_CheckChanged" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text="Bill Type:"></asp:Label>
        </div>     
        <div class="dlbilltydirDiv">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBillTypeDirect" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="140px">                
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="BillTypeDirectValidator" Text="*" 
                 ValidateEmptyText="true" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="TestValidation"
                 runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" OnServerValidate="ValidateBilltypedir_SeverValidate" 
                ControlToValidate="ddlBillTypeDirect"></asp:CustomValidator>
        </div>
        <div id= lbl2>
        checkbox
         lable2
        </div>
       <div id = dropdown2>
          dropdowncontrol2 
           customvalidator2
       </div>
    <div id= lbl3>
        checkbox3
         lable3
        </div>
       <div id = dropdown3>
          dropdownlist3
           customvalidator3
       </div>  
    ...................
     like this 
     in child div
</div>
```

Comment: please post some html and css, create a jsfiddle.

Comment: pls check it that css styles

Comment: html please, and create a jsfiddle, would be better.

Comment: i have posted some aspx code pls check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved My problem by putting content height as auto and  by putting each control(textbox and dropdown control)and corresponding label in one div  in side  child divs

if validation summary is appears on the top now it wont effect to child divs in parent div....